# Room Dao Impl both methods have same erasure

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

I am getting the following error in my room DAO, everything works as expected but not sure what this is about, any ideas?

Method in DAO is:

```kotlin
  @Query("SELECT * FROM ts_time_log WHERE timesheetStartDate == :date AND pending == 1")
  abstract suspend fun getPendingTimeLogsByWeekStartDate(date: LocalDate): List<TSTimeLog>
```

And the error:

[image]

Comment: The [example in the docs](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/accessing-data#kotlin-coroutines) for returning a collection from a suspend function uses `Array<T>`.  Changing your query from `List<TSTimeLog>` to `Array<TSTimeLog>`  resolves the error.  I'm still researching why returning a `List<T>` produces the error.

Comment: Interestingly it works - perhaps it has something to do with `Continuation` generics.